How to pass Russian characters from Java to Sql Server database
When filling the database (SQL Server) via Java with Russian words, they are displayed in the database with characters like these: "& # 1085". And the words are truncated when there is no reason for it. That is, the input field is designed for 30 characters, I fill the database through Java, for example, the word "диван" and it truncates it, writes characters in the database or does not enter it at all.  As I understand it, the truncation occurs precisely because its encoding is written instead of the word:
"& # 1086; & # 1045; & # 1015; & # 1035; ..." and it comes out to more than 30 characters, so it truncates.
Everything is fine with the English language, it displays and works correctly.
I tried adding "useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8" to the database connection string, but it didn't help.
And I'm also using nvarchar (30)
on the jsp page as well:
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

UPDATE:
method that adds to the database:
public static int insert(Product product) {
    if (connection !=null){
              
            String sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) Values (?, ?)";
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)){
                preparedStatement.setString(1, product.getName());
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, product.getPrice());
                  
                return  preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }            
            catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

UPDATE 2:
class Product:
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String name;
private int price;
 
public Product(){ }
public Product(String name, int price){
     
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
public Product(int id, String name, int price){
     
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
 
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
 
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}

UPDATE 3:
Index.jsp - this is where the data from the database is output:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Products List</h2>
<p><a href='<c:url value="/create" />'>Create new</a></p>
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr>
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
 <tr><td>${product.name}</td>
    <td>${product.price}</td>
    <td>
    <a href='<c:url value="/edit?id=${product.id}" />'>Edit</a> |
    <form method="post" action='<c:url value="/delete" />' style="display:inline;">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.id}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
 </td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Create.jsp - this is where you enter the data to be added to the database:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Create product</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>New product</h3>
<form method="post">
<label>Name</label><br>
<input name="name"/><br><br>
<label>Price</label><br>
<input name="price" type="number" min="100" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>


Show the code that does the actual database writing. It sounds like you entity-encode your data which isn't a standard driver-behavour

@siggemannen , I've added my code to the question description

what does product.getName() return? is it encoded? You should trace that value all the way from jsp

I very much doubt it. no unicode is encoded into entities when doing jdbc stuff, pretty sure the error is between jsp and the controller

@siggemannen , yes, product.getName() gives out "&# 1087;&# 1077;&# 1089;"
getName is a method in product that returns a string name, just in case, I've updated the information by adding code about this class.

I may be saying something ridiculous, but I noticed that on one jsp I didn't have a line:
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

I have 2 jsp pages - Index and Create. Index displays the name and price fields from the database. Create has fields where the user enters information in the database. The line
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
was only in Index. Apparently, data in the form of code was added to the database from Сreate, and Index displayed the code in the form of Russian characters.
After I added this string to create, I have the characters Ð "ÑƒÐºÐº in both the database and Index
I don't know if this information will help in search for an answer....

Since you seem to be using java.sql.PreparedStatement directly, have you tried calling setNString() against the nvarchar columns instead?

You have something that encodes values, perhaps your form already. You should probably post your jsp code, but i don't know, you should debug your code and see if values are encoded in request object already or what happens, do you use some framework like Spring around your jsp code? I haven't coded jsp for a few years, and not sure i'd like to revisit it :)

@siggemannen , no, I don't use Spring

@AlwaysLearning, you mean like this?
preparedStatement.setNString(1, product.getName());
If yes, it didn't help( The code of Russian characters is still displayed in the database, but not the characters themselves.

@siggemannen, I have added jsp pages to the question description. Does the fact that create.jsp does not have the line <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%> ? If I add it, it is not the code that appears in the database, but the characters Ð "Ñƒ. In index.jsp it also appears
Ð "Ñƒ after that. Maybe I need to change this line somehow? I don't know...

If you do that, and debug the getName() before insert into database, does the value look correct there

@siggemannen, product.getName() outputs string name=" "
Ð "Ñƒ "

@siggemannen – Usually, I would agree to "pretty sure the error is between jsp and the controller", but with MS SQL Server as the RDBMS, I am pretty sure the issue is in the JDBC driver, in the RDBMS or both.

@ᴥSaiLyᴥ – If you have the option, change the RDBMS (just for a test). You can use H2 or Derby (for example), as they can be embedded and do not need much setup. With that test you can at least eliminate the Java part from the suspects list.
